# CORS preflight call doesn't follow with the GET call

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

My JavaScript code needs to make the following GET Ajax call to a REST service:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://serverdomain.com/serviceurl,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 5000,
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
    success: function (data) {
        renderInfo(data);
    },
    error: function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        ...
    }
});
```

The following CORS preflight call is triggered because the Authorization HTTP header.

```
OPTIONS https://stcuatsoagw51.uatingdircan.ca:8443/sean/v1/customers/my/?_=1390845096145 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Origin: https://localhost:44300
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Host: stcuatsoagw51.uatingdircan.ca:8443
Content-Length: 0
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I changed the server side to return the following response to the OPTIONS call:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 27
Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2014 17:51:37 GMT
```

The response is essentially to allow all type of CORS calls. However, the browser seems to stop after receiving the OPTIONS call response and doesn't proceed to send out the original GET call.

Am I missing anything in the response to the OPTIONS call?

Comment: What are you seeing in your developer/javascript console?  Also, you can't use a wildcard for Access-Control-Allow-Origin if Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is true.  Do you really need cookies to be sent with your cross-origin GET request?

Comment: Thanks Ray. After getting rid of the two wildcards, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` you can't use a wildcard. You have to list out the headers. Also, as Ray said, you can't use a wildcard for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` if `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is set to true.

Comment: You can use a wildcard for Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: Really? It doesn't indicate that in the spec http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-headers-response-header Edit: I can't find any docs saying wildcards are permitted and other SO answers state they are not.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd.  The spec does indeed leave this out, suggesting it is not valid.  It looks like the MDN article that discusses this header is incorrect.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Headers